# Where does ARM read program instructions from after Register 14?

Tags: arm, opcode, instructions

How I understand the basic workings of the ARM architecture is such;

There are 15 main registers with the 15th (r15) being the Program Counter (PC).

If the program counter points to a specific register, then how can you have a Program which runs more than ~14 lines?

Obviously this is not true, but I don't understand how you can incorporate a big program with just 15 registers? What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think the code is stored in the registers?

Answer (score 5):

The program counter points to *memory*, not another register.

Comment: But then, can you have instructions in registers?

Comment: @user1255592: No. You might be able to load an instruction from memory into a register, but the processor won't look for instructions to execute in registers.

Comment: okay. That makes sense. So like you said, if I loaded an instruction from memory to a register, then can I ask the processor to run that instruction in the register?

Comment: @user1255592: No. You'd have to store it back into memory and then tell the processor to start executing from that location in memory. The processor does not retrieve code from registers; it retrieves it from memory *pointed to* by `r15`.

Answer (score 5):

Registers don't store the program code.  Program code is in main memory, and the Program Counter points to the location in memory of the next instruction.

The other registers are high-speed locations for storing temporary, or frequently accessed, values during the processing of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form, you have Program (Instruction memory), Data memory, Stack Memory, and Registers.

ARM instructions are stored in the Instruction memory, they are a sequence of commands which tell the processor what to do. They are never stored in the registers of the processor. The program counter only points to that instruction, that instruction is simply a command which in the basic form has an opcode (operation code) and variables/literals ..

So what happens is that the instruction is read from memory (fetched) from the location pointed to by the program counter.  It is not loaded into the registers, but the control unit where it is decoded (that is to know what operation to do, i.e. add, sub, mov etc) and where to read/store its inputs and outputs.

So where are the inputs/outputs to operate on and store? The ARM architecture is a load/store architecture, it means it operates on data loaded into its registers, that is R1, R2 .. R7 ..etc .. where the registers could be thought of as temporary variables where all inputs and outputs are stored. Registers are used because they are so fast and operate at the same speed of the processor frequency not as memory which is slower.

Now the question is, how to populate these registers with values in the first place?

Those values could be stored on the Data Memory or Stack memory, so there are instructions to copy them to these registers, followed by instructions to operate on them and store the value in the registers, then followed by other instructions to copy the result back to Memory. Some instructions could also load a register with a constant.

```
Instruction 1 // Copy Variable X into R1 from memory
Instruction 2 // Copy Variable Y into R2 from memory
ADD, R3, R1, R2 // add them together
Instruction 3 // Copy back the result into Memory
```

I tried to make it as simple as possible, there are so many details to cover. Needs books :)